# generated aliases error in spring JPA in criteria query API

Tags: spring-boot, criteriaquery

```
    public Predicate get_data(String field, String method, String value) throws Exception
   {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<student> cq = cb.createQuery(student.class);
    Root<student> s = cq.from(student.class);
    Predicate selected_field = null;
    number = new BigDecimal(value);


    if(method.equals("greaterThan") || method.equals("greaterThanOrEqualTo") || 
           method.equals("lessThan") || method.equals("lessThanOrEqualTo"))
    {
        Method cbMethod = cb.getClass().getMethod(method,Expression.class,Comparable.class); 

        selected_field = (Predicate) cbMethod.invoke(cb,s.get(field), number);
    }

    else if(method.equals("eq"))
    {
        method = "equal";
        Method cbMethod = cb.getClass().getMethod(method,Expression.class,Object.class);
        selected_field = (Predicate) cbMethod.invoke(cb,s.get(field),number);
    }

    return selected_field;
}


public List<student> get(String search) throws Exception
{
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<student> cq = cb.createQuery(student.class);
    Root<student> s = cq.from(student.class);
    List<Predicate> selected_field = new ArrayList<>();

    System.out.println(search);
    List<String> query = Arrays.asList(search.split("And",0));
    System.out.println(query.size());
    List<String> fields = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> method = new ArrayList<>();


    for (String str : query)
    {
        List<String> s1 = null;

        int index_lt = str.indexOf('<');
        int index_gt = str.indexOf('>');
        int index_eq = str.indexOf('=');

        if(index_lt != -1)
        {
            s1 = Arrays.asList(str.split("<",0));
            method.add("lessThan");
        }


        else if(index_gt != -1)
        {
            s1 = Arrays.asList(str.split(">",0));
            method.add("greaterThan");
        }


        else if(index_eq != -1)
        {
            s1 = Arrays.asList(str.split("=",0));
            method.add("equal");
        }

        System.out.println("S1"+s1);
        fields.add("student_"+s1.get(0));
        values.add(s1.get(1));
    }


    for(int i = 0 ; i < fields.size() ; i++)
    {

        selected_field.add(get_data(fields.get(i),method.get(i),values.get(i)));

    }


    cq.where(cb.and(selected_field.toArray(new Predicate[] {})));
    cq.where(predicatesarr);
    System.out.println("where ends");


    TypedQuery<student> search_query = em.createQuery(cq);

    return search_query.getResultList();

}
```

when I am sending this http://localhost:8080/?search=rollNo>13 then it is giving me this error.
`org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: 'generatedAlias1.student_rollNo' [select generatedAlias0 from io.poc_task1.poc_task1.student as generatedAlias0 where generatedAlias1.student_rollNo>13]`

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.